# Specifying correct library to link in Xcode when multiple copies exist on search path

Tags: c++, xcode, ffmpeg, iconv

I am trying to compile a C++ file that depends on ffmpeg. I have spent a long time trying to fix all the link errors. I found that on the Mac it needs:

```
libbz2.dylib
libiconv.dylib
libz.dylib
libavcodec.a
libavformat.a
libswscale.a
libswresample.a
VideoDecodeAcceleration.framework
CodeVideo.framework
CoreFoundation.framework
```

The problem I have is that I still get symbol link errors for `libiconv` even though the library is present in `/usr/lib` and all the other libraries in this directory are being found there. The compile line includes `-liconv.2`

On searching around I found that the problem comes from there being two version of `libiconv` on my system. One is in `/usr/lib` and the other is in `/opt/local/lib`. The one in `/usr/lib` exports symbols that ffmpeg uses named like "`_iconv_open`", whereas the one in `/opt/local/lib` exports the same symbols with "`lib`" added, e.g. "`_libiconv_open`". It seems the compiler is picking up the `/opt/local/lib` library.

How can I get Xcode to pick up the correct lib?

Comment: Why -liconv.2? You should use -liconv, without the ".2" suffix.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but thats not the issue. Xcode adds the .2 because libiconv.dylib in /usr/lib is symbolically linked to libiconv.2.dylib - its just the version number of the actual lib. When I add libiconv.dylib Xcode changes it to the .2 version.